# Mozilla firefox makes laggy my jquery slideDown animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I've met this problem nowadays. I have a div which contains li-img (5of them) and when I try to reappear it with the slideDown animation 3/10 its smooth on mozilla and over 11/11 in chrome. The code and computer is the same and the exact problem is that the slidedown is smooth but the images are not slowing appear as the div appear, sometimes are completely invisible and then suddenly appear. Its not a matter of asyc coding cause i even tried to setTimeout(300) between append and animation but append is synchronous. The only plugin in mozilla is ad-block as in my chrome too. (I know that mozilla considered more heavy browser while chrome considered faster but eats more ram).  The code is this (i really dont think its code problem)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//classes
var $wrapper= $(".wrapper");
var $header=$wrapper.find(".header");
var $center = $wrapper.find(".center");
var $quiz=$center.find(".quiz");
// buttons-li
var $header_li= $header.find("ul li");
//other elements
var $quiz=$wrapper.find(".quiz");
var $rope = $wrapper.find("#rope")
var $popup;
function getQuiz(){
    $.get('./php/get_quiz.php',function(data)
    {
        $quiz.append("<ul>"+data+"</ul>");
        //setTimeout(ropeAnimation,100);
        ropeAnimation();
        toImgsAddPointer();
        $rope.unbind('click');
        $rope.removeClass('pointer');
    });
}
function submitAnswer(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.get('./php/result.php',{'choice':id},function(data){
        var $ul= $center.find("ul");
        $ul.remove();
        $quiz.append("<ul>"+data+"</ul>");
        toImgsAddPointer();
    });
}
function clickEvent(){
    var purple= '#5061FF';
    var white = 'white';
    var red= 'red';
    var black = 'black';
    $(this).css('background-color',purple).css('color',white);
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color',red).css('color',black);
    if(this.id==1){
        var div = "<div class='popup'><object data='./pdf/math1.pdf'></object></div";
    }else{
        var div = "<div class='popup'><object data='./pdf/math2.pdf'></object></div";
    }
    $wrapper.prepend(div);
    $popup=$(".popup");
    $popup.on('click',closePopup);
}
function closePopup(){
    $popup.remove();
}
function ropeAnimation(){
    $rope.animate({"height":'200px'},100);
    $quiz.slideDown(500);
    $rope.animate({"height":'50px'},700);
}
function toImgsAddPointer(){
    var $img = $quiz.find("li img");
    $img.addClass("pointer");
    $img.on('click',submitAnswer);
}
$header_li.on('click',clickEvent);
$header_li.addClass("pointer");
$rope.addClass("pointer");
$rope.on('click',getQuiz);
});
```

The animation is in get_quiz() with ropeanimation().

Comment: Try to reproduce this in a simple test case, with a HTML element and the jQuery code.

Comment: Yeah , even with 2 single li the mozilla loses a lot of fps. I mean in chrome I can even see first the element appear in the started position and then the animation begins while in mozilla it shows me already the animation

Comment: What I meant was, make a test case, for instance on JSFiddle, so we can see it for ourselves.